# Standard name for method to check and set a variable

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I am aware that the 'standard' name for methods to check and to change the value of a boolean variable X are `getX()`, `isX()` and `setX()`.

Is there a standard name for a method which returns the value and changes it after returning it but only the first time (i.e. I cannot use `toggleX()` because it will only toggle the first time)? I want to have a method which returns true only the first time it is called, so something like:

```
public boolean isFirstExecution() {
    if (mIsFirstExecution) {
        mIsFirstExecution = false;
        return true;
    } else {
        return mIsFirstExecution;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I think it might be confusing to have a method called isX() changing the value of a variable.

Comment: Could you post another example of what you mean? The one you posted, isFirstExecution, is mostly fine like that, with the exception that you should use a static variable internal to the method, if your language supports them.
(continues below)

Comment: (continuation)
In particular, in general there's nothing wrong with 'a method called isX() changing the value of a variable'. If methods' names had to explain all the internal operations that the methods do you'd have to use their entire source code as their name. What the name has to express is what the method does at the level of abstraction that matters to its user; if the method needs to modify a variable to realize what its name abstractly describes that's nothing of concern to the person calling the method.

Comment: Yes, I guess my problem is that I didn't realize that the caller doesn't know anything about the internals, so whatever happens behind the curtains is irrelevant (there might not even be a variable in the first place!). If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Well thanks but it wouldn't really be an answer to the literal question you posted, I'd have at least to change it a bit, I'm fine like this. Upvote the comment if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there's specific name for the function that you are intend to make.
Just specify the purpose of function when you name it. Not too long but specific enough so that others also can recognize when they see your code.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't feel comfortable with having side effects in a function named `isX()`. I guess it is not too bad as long as it is documented in the internals of the class implementing the method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to have that method do two things – check and set.  Instead you can have two methods, `isFirstExecution()` (that is a check `mIsFirstExecution`) and `executedFirstTime()` (that will turn off `mIsFirstExecution`.)

All of this seems too "enterprisey" though, I would suggest just exposing `mIsFirstExecution` directly to callers, and doing away with the methods.

Comment: The problem with the two methods is that, by experience, I know maintainers will forget to call the second method at some point, so I want it to be 'atomic'. And I am afraid it needs to be "enterprisey", it's not a personal project :)